# Torch / cunn install error - file already has LC_RPATH

Tags: torch

I'm trying to install cunn for Torch but make install fails. Cuda is 7.5.27 because 8 doesn't support OSX 10.10 anymore.

I've been trying to debug this for a while, but I'm running out of things to try.

While searching solution I saw few others having a similar problem (https://github.com/TRIQS/cthyb/issues/8, https://github.com/jcjohnson/neural-style/issues/134) but didn't find any solution that would fix this. It seems that this is a general problem related to OSX/Xcode and not necessarily cunn.

All help is much appreciated.

```
$ luarocks install cunn
...
...
-- Installing: /Users/foo/torch/install/lib/luarocks/rocks/cunn/scm-1/lib/libTHCUNN.so
error: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/install_name_tool: for: 
/Users/foo/torch/install/lib/luarocks/rocks/cunn/scm-1/lib/libTHCUNN.so (for architecture x86_64) option "-add_rpath /usr/local/cuda/lib" 
would duplicate path, file already has LC_RPATH for: /usr/local/cuda/lib
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue went away when I did `./clean.sh` in `~/torch` followed by `./update.sh`. I still don't have any idea what was the problem.